# Intellisense for C# User Control in VB.NET project

Tags: c#, vb.net, intellisense

I have created a C# user control which I want to use in VB.NET .. the control works fine, but in VB.NET the Intellisense does not show any of the C# user control function descriptions (in summary xml doc tag).

If I use the same control in a C# project the Intellisense show each function's description as intended..

is this normal ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal.  However, in Visual Studio 2010 the intellisense support for C# and VB.NET is much better.  I always found that the intellisense for VB.NET was lacking in 2008, but VS 2010 has improved in that area.